# Reordering a vector into another repeating one in matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a vector of the form:

```
A = [a1 a2 a3 a4 ...];
```

I want to create another vector like this:

```
B = [a1 a1 a1 a2 a2 a2 a3 a3 a3 a4 a4 a4 ...];
```

How can i do this?

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to do this, for instance using the [Kronecker tensor product](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/kron.html) like this:

```
B = kron(A,ones(1,3))
```

or combining [`reshape`](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html) and [`repmat`](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/repmat.html) like this:

```
B = reshape(repmat(A,3,1),1,[])
```

if you're not sure if the vector is horizontal or vertical, you can use `(:)` and the transpose `.'` like this:

```
B = kron(A(:).', ones(1,3))
B = reshape(repmat(A(:).',3,1),1,[])
```

**EDIT**

You said the reshape version didn't work. Here are the results from my tests:

```
A = 1:4
B = reshape(repmat(A(:).',3,1),1,[])
B =
   1   1   1   2   2   2   3   3   3   4   4   4
A = (1:4)'
B = reshape(repmat(A(:).',3,1),1,[])
B =
   1   1   1   2   2   2   3   3   3   4   4   4
```

So, it works for both column and row vectors (at least for me).

Some more ways to do it:

```
%# vector-matrix product
reshape(ones(3,1)*A, 1,[])

%# reorganize simple concatenation
nA = 3*numel(A);    
B([1:3:nA 2:3:nA 3:3:nA]) = [A A A];
```

Comment: Among these many ways, which one is fastest?

Comment: I suggest you test this yourself using [`timeit`](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/timeit.html). It would be nice if you share the benchmark results here when you've tested it =)

Comment: I tested it for a vector of random numbers with 1000 elements and repeating factor of 300, the time for kron function was t1=0.0373 and the time for reshape function was t2 = 0.0091. something about four times faster

Comment: Ok, this makes sense since `kron` involves arithmetic operations whereas repmat simply repeats the values. You can have a look at Luis' answer in the duplicate question. I haven't tested it, but it might be it's a bit faster.

Comment: The reshape form does not working, it does not repeat each element, it repeats the whole vector!. In Luis answer what is the 1,2 and 3? how can i improve it for any vector?

Comment: @user3482383: Please see my update. And [1;2;3] is the vector he wants do duplicate.